# How to map the guids under /var/lib/kubelet/pods to the actual pods

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kubernetes-pod

I was trying to debug some mount problems and the mount logs led me to paths under `/var/lib/kubelet/pods`, i.e

`/var/lib/kubelet/pods/f6affad1-941d-4df1-a0b7-38e3f2ab99d5/volumes/kubernetes.io~nfs/my-pv-e0dbe341a6fe475c9029fb372e`

How can I map the guid of the root directory under `pods` to the actual running pod or container?

(`f6affad1-941d-4df1-a0b7-38e3f2ab99d5` in the example above)

I don't see any correlation to the values returned by `kubectl` or `crictl`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They're the `.metadata.uid` of the Pod; one can map them back by using your favorite mechanism for querying all pods and filtering on its `.metadata.uid`, and optionally restricting to just those pods scheduled on that Node if you have a so many Pods as to make the `-A` infeasible

```sh
for d in /var/lib/kubelet/pods/*; do
  p_u=$(basename "$d")
  kubectl get po -A -o json | \
    jq --arg pod_uuid "$p_u" -r '.items[] 
      | select(.metadata.uid == $pod_uuid) 
      | "uuid \($pod_uuid) is \(.metadata.name)"'
done
```

I'm sure there is a `-o jsonpath=` or `-o gotemplate=` form that removes the need for `jq` but that'd be a lot more work to type out in a textarea

with regard to your `crictl` question, I don't this second have access to my containerd cluster, but the docker based one labels the local containers with `io.kubernetes.pod.uid` so I would guess containerd does something similar:

```json
            "Labels": {
                "annotation.io.kubernetes.container.hash": "e44bee94",
                "annotation.io.kubernetes.container.restartCount": "4",
                "annotation.io.kubernetes.container.terminationMessagePath": "/dev/termination-log",
                "annotation.io.kubernetes.container.terminationMessagePolicy": "File",
                "annotation.io.kubernetes.pod.terminationGracePeriod": "30",
                "io.kubernetes.container.logpath": "/var/log/pods/kube-system_storage-provisioner_b4aa3b1c-62c1-4661-a302-4c06b305b7c0/storage-provisioner/4.log",
                "io.kubernetes.container.name": "storage-provisioner",
                "io.kubernetes.docker.type": "container",
                "io.kubernetes.pod.name": "storage-provisioner",
                "io.kubernetes.pod.namespace": "kube-system",
                "io.kubernetes.pod.uid": "b4aa3b1c-62c1-4661-a302-4c06b305b7c0",
                "io.kubernetes.sandbox.id": "3950ec60121fd13116230cad388a4c6c4e417c660b7da475436f9ad5c9cf6738"
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

A simpler way to map to the pod name that does not require `kubectl` and relies on a container name saved in filesystem is:

```bash
ls -lad /var/lib/kubelet/pods/*/containers/*

# Sample output:
# /var/lib/kubelet/pods/0a82722a-57e7-4a32-b0e7-1d3864b98c98/containers/worker
# /var/lib/kubelet/pods/148c7195-c3ab-4750-afb4-e6fb34948ed5/containers/dashboard
# /var/lib/kubelet/pods/6bb42e72-902d-49b1-8beb-0e885e2708fc/containers/kube-proxy
# ...

find /var/lib/kubelet/pods/ -maxdepth 3 -name "*dnsutils*"

# Sample output:
# /var/lib/kubelet/pods/a18df6c7-3a37-4bc0-8593-026145f4c4b6/containers/dnsutils
```